# why next button is disabled in xamarin studio?

Tags: xamarin

I installed the `xamarin studio` and next button is disabled when I want to create a new project.
What should I do?

next button is disabled:-

[image]

Comment: This is because you don't have android SDK set up on your system. The Traget Platform needs to be checked to enable the next button. But as it is disabled you might not have the android SDK.

Comment: where can I download androis sdk?

Answer (score 0):

To hit the 'next' button you will have to have an Android SDK installed so you can check the box next to the Android Target Platform.

I believe Xamarin Studio installs with the Android SDK Manager installed, try searching for it on your computer (SDK Manager). Once you install at least 1 SDK in the manager you should be able to hit next.

Answer (score 0):

its picture of android sdk manager in program files & other android sdk manager when I clicked open android sdk manager in visual studio 2015.
[image of android sdk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqwhN.png)